# Importing System.Web.Script.Serialization in Xamarin

Tags: json, xamarin, system.web

I wanted to use `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize` to convert a JSON array string to a list of objects. But this class uses the the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` in Xamarin namespace. So I wanted to import the `System.Web` assembly in my project to use the namespace, but System.Web or any similar assembly does not exist in the packages.
I found out that I can use `JSON.Net` to solve this issue.
But I still have the question: Is there a way to import the `System.Web`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot import `System.Web` straight like that as far as I know. I'm using [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net), they claim to be the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to import System.Web, only System.Web.Services but I think it's not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web related stuffs are dedicate to ASP.NET. Thus, it is meaningless for Xamarin to include them in any of its mobile platforms. Even Microsoft itself does not do so for Windows RT and Windows Phone.

As you already find that JSON.NET can solve your problem, you'd better close the question before anyone votes for closure.